# Materializecss wordpress mobile side menu in a collapsible

Tags: php, wordpress, materialize

I've been trying to make a wordpress theme using MaterializeCSS. I've got almost everything working, except for my mobile side menu. In my menu I have 4 main items, with subpages beneath them. I want to show this in the same way in the side menu, using the "collapsible" class. In a test environment where I don't create the menu items dynamically I can make it work, but whenever I want to let the menu created by Wordpress I can't make it happen.

I know I should use a navwalker, and I have been fiddling with it for several hours already, but I can't get it to work.

Fiddle of what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/bdf7yvbc

```
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="collapsible-header">MSG</a>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="bestuur.php">Bestuur</a></li>
        <li><a>Commissies</a></li>
        <li><a>Agenda</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you give us a link to the Wordpress page where the navigation doesn't work as expected? The fiddle looks OK so I don't know exactly how we could help.

Comment: Yeah, the problem isn't that I can't create it. I just don't know how to translate it into a working wordpress type menu.

The site I want to use it at is: http://www.msg.utwente.nl/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to do it while not using wp_nav_menu and a walker, but using wp_get_nav_menu_items.

My code, if anyone is interested:

```
<?php

$menu_name = 'Side-Nav'; //Name as shown in Appearance -> Menus

if ( ($menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_name ) ) && ( isset($menu) ) ) {
  $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
  ?>

  <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        $link = $item->url;
        $title = $item->title;
        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li>
      <a class="collapsible-header"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                </li>

            <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
            </ul>
            <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>                           
    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

<?php $count++; endforeach; }?>
```